Converting cif file with powdll, plotting cif file in excel
When I press convert in powdll converter software, I get this error message "Object reference not set to an instance of an object". I haven't been able to convert any kind of file type because of this. I want to convert cif files into excel files so that I can plot the value next to the experimental value. I need to change the x-axis and y-axis values of the theoretical pattern and plot it together with my experimental pattern so standard plotting software like Mercury won't work for me. If there is an alternative way you know of how to plot a cif file in excel, that would be helpful as well.
Thank you.

If you want to plot a theoretical powder diffractogram (PXRD), i.e. diffraction intensity (arbitrary units along the ordinate) in function of diffraction angle $2\theta$ (in degrees along the abscissa) for a particular wavelength, and already have Mercury installed, check if you can stay with it.  Even the Free Community edition is fine to load the .cif file in question for a prediction (calculate -> power pattern).
The prediction

can be be adjusted for instance about the wavelength used during the diffraction experiment (if not $\ce{Cu K_\alpha{}}$, say $\lambda(\ce{Mo K_\alpha) = \pu{0.71073 Å}}$).

The export of the prediction can either be a bitmap (Save image...), or data table (Save...) in multiple formats suitable for a superposition with data you recorded with a spreadsheat like gnumeric, Excel (or fityk) as you intend.  Other formats (e.g., for DASH, or Bruker's binary .raw format) are set for future crystallographic work down the road, too.  Hence I would recommend to use the export as 2-column, tab separated format (angle, intensity -- which you could amplify/attenuate by subsequent multiplication):
5   0
5.02    0
5.04    1.85977
5.06    1.91139
5.08    1.96519
...

to plot the trace, and an export as $(hkl)$ reflection list to annotate the reflection indices (if required):
     h      k      l  d-spacing       F^2     multiplicity
     0      0      2   13.5674      2020.75        2
     0      1      1   10.3612      489.183        4
     0      1      2    8.6421      1001.44        4
     1      0      1   7.81184      696.894        4
     0      1      3   7.03944      9169.33        4
...

The preview plot by Mercury is interactive, i.e. the widget can be scaled and while you hover the mouse pointer over the diffractogram both the current $2\theta$ angle (in degrees) as well the $(hkl)$ indices -- if available (the purple ticks) -- are read out.
Contrasting to a program dedicated to PXRD (GSAS etc.), Mercury's predicted diffraction pattern does not account for e.g., preferred orientation of sample crystals in PXRD.  That is, filling needle shaped crystals into the capillary like arrows into a quiver (transmission geometry), or laying plate shaped crystals on the dish like records flat on a shelf (reflection geometry) can affect individual diffraction intensities such that some are intensified and others attenuated in comparison to the diffraction pattern of finely ground sample crystals in random orientations. In the setting of an introductory lab class (e.g. with a reference .cif file by CCDC/ICSD or COD), this might not be an issue if only a couple of diffraction peaks are considered / quantification of components (presence of multiple minerals, or polymorphs/crystal phases in one sample) is not the aim of the analysis.

The more modern (ShelXL generated) .cif files optionally can include the already reduced data of the diffraction experiment like a separate .hkl file, i.e. the reflection indices $(h,k,l)$, the square of diffraction intensity $F^2_{obs}$ extracted of a diffraction experiment, the width of the particular extracted diffraction signal $\sigma(F^2_{obs})$ in a Fortran accessible format of 3I4,2F8.2,I4 plus an optional batch number (e.g., to reflect the origin of the data from multiple measurement series).  This data block is for archival purposes, to facilitate to some degree a replication of structure solution an refinement and quality checks (especially with a structure factor / .fcf files) with services like Platon / checkcif, see e.g. Sheldrick 2015.
Sheldrick, G. M. Crystal Structure Refinement with SHELXL. Acta Cryst. C 2015, 71, 3–8. doi 10.1107/S2053229614024218 (open access)

I was able to export the pattern as a .tsv file using mercury! Thank You.
